# Troubleshoot Persistent Crashing of Task Blocker on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crash, process

There's a free app called [Task Blocker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taskblocker/) which I've found very useful for over a year. A few days ago it quit working. Every time I launch it Windwows immediately informs me that it has quit working and gives the following details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: taskblocker.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.5.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 51c7ed73
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18444
  Problem Signature 06: 52717edc
  Problem Signature 07: 86b
  Problem Signature 08: 29
  Problem Signature 09: System.FormatException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.27
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

The only website listed for this app is the download site I linked above and I do not see a developer's website or GitHub repo when i search for it. I'm unsure if this question is better suited for Superuser or StackOverflow, so please feel free to move it if I'm in error by posting it here.

I have tried

1. uninstalling and re-installing the program
2. re-starting the computer
3. Looking for changes to my computer between when the app was working and when it started crashing (can't find or recall any changes to the system)
4. web searching several different pieces of information in the problem signature -- None of them bring up results specific to this app and when I followed the solutions associated with other apps such as Windows Media Center it was not productive.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your anti-virus software?  It might be picking it up as a malicious program.

Comment: here is the code in a SVN repository: http://sourceforge.net/p/taskblocker/code/HEAD/tree/ check it out, compile it and debug it yourself.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Thanks, I tried that since you suggested it but it still won't run

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, but I'm not a software developer and I'm not suggesting that the program is fundamentally flawed and needs to be re-written. Maybe there's some setting in Windows that needs to be changed?

Comment: no, this is a bug inside the tool. You can't fix this with a setting

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I got this to work...

Right-click on the .exe or desktop icon > Properties > Compatibility > select "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and select "Windows XP (Service Pack 3)" AND "Run this program as an administrator: under Privilege Level > select "Change settings for all users" (if you desire) and do the same > click OK > click OK and run the program. It should prompt the UAC to pop up to give it access to run, so it seems it may be some kind of permissions issue.

Not sure if this will stick after a reboot yet, though, but I had this issue, too (on a Win 7 HP 64-bit PC). Hope this helps!